# refreshing a layout without recreating the activity on orientation change

Tags: android, android-layout, android-orientation

I prevent activity recreated on orientation changes in my app.

```
<activity
      android:name=".ActivityA"
      android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" >
 </activity>
```

But i have two values folders, one for values-land. And i defined a string resource with same key and different values accordingly orientation. But when user rotates the app TextViews text not changing. Is it possible to force to refresh layout to use correct string resource?

Answer (score 0):

You try override this

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);
}
```

Comment: Okey this good but what if ı have one fragment in layout and others in backstack how can i reload the same fragment structure?